How to use bytes (encode/decode) in Protobuf (C++)?
Lets say I have a simple Protobuf message like:
syntax = "proto3";

package package;

message WriteBlock
{
  uint32 address = 1;
  uint32 size = 2;
  bytes data = 3;
}

Now I create a variable writeBlock of this type:
package_WriteBlock writeBlock = package_WriteBlock_init_zero;

How do I fill writeBlock.data?

The documentation tells, that the type bytes will be translated to a string. If I check my translation:
typedef struct _package_ReadAgg {
    uint32_t address;
    uint32_t size;
    pb_callback_t data;
} package_ReadAgg;

With pb_callback_t beeing:
typedef struct pb_callback_s pb_callback_t;
struct pb_callback_s {
    /* Callback functions receive a pointer to the arg field.
     * You can access the value of the field as *arg, and modify it if needed.
     */
    union {
        bool (*decode)(pb_istream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void **arg);
        bool (*encode)(pb_ostream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void * const *arg);
    } funcs;

    /* Free arg for use by callback */
    void *arg;
};

So, how do I store a simple std::uint8_t byteArray[20] in this data field?? Do I have to use encode(...)? What does these parameters mean?
I didn't find any explanation how to fill this type of thing :/

This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344214/nanopb-without-callbacks/31345690#31345690

Your question is tagged C++. Do you want to use C or C++, and if C++, then why are you using unofficial nanopb for C?

The explanation you're looking for is in the nanopb documentation

Thanks for your replys! I took on this code and have to extend its features. I missed the difference between Proto and nanopb ...

This is how I done it now:
constexpr std::size_t BlockMaxSize = 33;
    
bool encodeData(pb_ostream_t* stream, const pb_field_t* field, void* const* arg)
{
    const char* str = (const char*)(*arg);

    if (!pb_encode_tag_for_field(stream, field))
        return false;

    return pb_encode_string(stream, (uint8_t*)str, strlen(str));
}

void createBlockMessage(std::uint8_t _address, std::size_t _size)
{
    package_WriteBlock writeBlock = package_WriteBlock_init_zero;
    writeBlock.address = _address;
    std::uint8_t data[BlockMaxSize];
    WriteBlockData(_address, data, _size);
    writeBlock.data.arg = data;
    writeBlock.data.funcs.encode = &encodeData;

    std::uint8_t buffer[2 * BlockMaxSize]; // How do I calculate this size?
    pb_ostream_t ostream = pb_ostream_from_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    const auto result = pb_encode(&ostream, package_WriteBlock_fields, &writeBlock);
    // Do something with the result ...
}

How to encode a string when it is a pb_callback_t type

How do I calculate the size of the buffer needed with this type of dynamic message?

This is a separate question from what I'm seeing. Create a new question, reference the current one.

You probably should not use strlen to determine the length of str if it is indeed a generic bag of bytes.

pb_get_encoded_size, which calls pb_encode with a dummy stream and reports the number of bytes written.

@Botje You are completly right with strlen. But how do I actually get the size of arg in this callback function?

Make arg point to a struct that contains both a pointer and a length. You can use the C++ standard library std::span or even std::string for that.
